# Google Map Is Not Showing After Build In Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Google map is showing after making build but it is showing in browser while development.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Google map is not showing after making build but it is showing in browser while development.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: please post your code so we can help you